# os.path.exists in python does not work with visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a function that will check if there is a valid username stored in data/userData.txt, returns false if there is no valid username and returns true if there is a valid username
But before I want to check that the username is valid I want to first run a test that will check if userData.txt exists using os.path.exists.

This is the piece of code I used to check this

```
import os
def userFile(): #returns true if valid username exists
    if not os.path.exists('data/userData.txt'):
        print ('False') #debug
        return False
    else: #debug
        print('True')
    userData = open('data/userData.txt','r')
    #code to check if the username is valid
    userData.close
userFile()
```

But every time I run my code I get a False even tho the file itself exists but when I use IDLE my code works perfectly fine.

Am I running VSC in some sort of safemode that doesnt let it access files? But then it also writes to files perfectly fine.

Comment: You are checking if the file referenced by a *relative* path exists. Relative paths are resolved against the current working directory, which may be different depending on how you execute your code.

Comment: Right.  Remember that a relative path does NOT mean "relative to where the script is".  It means "relative to the current directory for this process."

Comment: You might want to check relative to the source path, as in `os.path.dirname(__file__)` in Python-speak.

Comment: Also, checking that file exists is prone to race condition. Use try/except instead and handle the error if file does not exists

Comment: @chepner How would I change the path so that it runs the .py where its stored rather than a preset location?

Comment: @TimRoberts Got it, is this different in different IDEs then since it works with IDLE and replit? How do I change that directory so that its relative to where the script is rather than relative to the current directory?

Comment: You can find the directory containing the script by using `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Running it gives me the following output
`d:\Programming Project`
but thats where my userData folder is and its reading from a different location.

Comment: Right.  That's NOT the "current directory".  That's just the location where the script lives.  If you don't want to to build the paths, do `os.chdir(xxx)` where `xxx` is the output of that expression.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you, I just added this line at the front of my program and now it works perfectly fine.
`os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))`
but shouldn't this be changed from within VSC rather than in my code? oh also just another note that running this in debug mode makes it read from the correct directory but normally running it makes it read from another directory where it is saving and reading files.

Comment: VSCode is just your editor.  It is the responsibility of your script to find its files, no matter what the "current directory" is when you run it, no matter how it gets run.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It must be determined under which path python is opened
so as not to make the same mistake as me.
[Look this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYCSl.png)

Comment: I figured it out, its because i didnt have a folder open so the terminal was set to the default path which was something along the lines of C:\Users\.
Using cd to change that to D:\Programming Project helped temporarily but I would need to run it everytime so I eventually stumbled on opening folders and that fixed it.